# Why am I getting a Status Code: 400 Bad Request error with WP Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have been troubleshooting this for hours now and I am stumped as to why this error is occurring.

in my JS I have the following ajax:

```js
var $ = jQuery; // define jquery
let name = "Mark";
let pies = "cherry";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : ajaxurl,
        nonce: nonce,
        data : {
            action: 'myfunction',
            name: name,
            pies: pies,
            nonce: nonce
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}); // end document ready
```

and in my plugin's PHP, I have

```php
    function myfunction() {    
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'registration_nonce')) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $pies = $_POST['pies'];
            file_put_contents('debug_output.txt', $pies);
            die();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfunction', 'myfunction' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction', 'myfunction');
```

This gives me a 400 every single time. This should be a simple thing and I normally do this all of the time but for some reason, I am seriously missing something. Any ideas anyone? I whittled it done to the bare minimum and still no luck. Both the ajax URL and nonce are fine. Did something in WP change?

Comment: Is `wpnonce` in your payload a variable you have previously defined? What does it contain?

Comment: @El_Vanja wpnonce is a defined variable and shows up in the payload correctly. I did notice when inspecting the request in devtools it shows as formdata so I tried removing `dataType: "json"` and even sending as JSON and using stringify. No luck.

Comment: Maybe your action hooks are not being registered on time by WordPress and so WordPress doesn't know they exist, hence the Bad Request response? (Which Diego below also suggested). Can you create a stripped down version of your plugin so we can help you debug it? (See [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that maybe you should fix/check:

1. in your PHP action end with something like echo json_encode($myDataArray) where $myDataArray is something like array("key" => "value") ecc..
2. Your last function call inside the PHP action should always be "die" or "exit" or just use the WP wp_send_json(); (you have alternatives for success/errors)
3. Double check that ajaxurl actually points to admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
4. Double check that your add_action hooks get called somewhere in your page before the AJAX call actually occours

Comment: I whittled it down to the bare minimum and edited the code above with no luck.. just 400 after 400. Any ideals anyone??

Comment: Is that the ONLY ajax function which is not working in your website? like test any backend wp ajax and if you find some, maybe a frontend one

Comment: #4 was the charm. I moved the add_action higher in the code and it worked. Cheers.

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if that solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Typo?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myactiont', 'myaction');

// should be

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'myaction');

// final result

function myaction(){
  echo "success";
  exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'myaction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'myaction');
```

Diego's answer has some good points to check too.

Comment: Yes.. a typo when I recreated for SO :-) Gotta keep the company stuff off public forums. LOL