# Yet another WordPress Ajax 400 Bad Request problem

Tags: wordpress

I am certain I am making a basic mistake here. I am getting the lovely 400 Bad Request response from WordPress when I try to make an Ajax call. I have one Ajax call that works, and this one that does not. I have looked at several posts both here and elsewhere, but remain stumped as to where I have erred.

Okay, the relevant code. First, here is how I do the add_action and script registration:

```
if ($_GET["page"] == "krudkat_data_structures") {
    add_action("wp_ajax_krud_save_new_connection", "krud_save_new_connection");
}

// Other Stuff, for the Ajax call that works.

if ($_GET["page"] == "krudkat_data_structures") {
    wp_register_script("krud_data_structures", plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . "/js/dataStructures.js", array("jquery"));
    wp_localize_script("krud_data_structures", "krudAjax", array( "ajaxurl" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")));
    wp_enqueue_script("krud_data_structures");
}
```

This sits in a function outside of a class. My JS call is like this:

```
var krudNewConnect = { action:"krud_save_new_connection",
    dbname:$("#krud_new_dbname").val().trim(),
    dbhost:$("#krud_new_dbhost").val().trim(),
    dbconnect:$("#krud_new_dbconnect").val().trim(),
    dbusername:$("#krud_new_dbusername").val().trim(),
    dbpassword:$("#krud_new_dbpassword").val() };
$.post(krudAjax.ajaxurl, krudNewConnect, function(newConnectData) {
    console.log(newConnectData);
});
```

Finally, my PHP method is, thus far, very simple:

```
function krud_save_new_connection() {
    $dbname = $_POST["dbname"];
    $dbhost = $_POST["dbhost"];
    $dbconnect = $_POST["dbconnect"];
    $dbusername = $_POST["dbusername"];
    $dbpassword = $_POST["dbpassword"];
    $dbport = 0;
    $dbsocket = '';
    if (!empty($dbconnect)) {
        if (is_numeric($dbconnect)) {
            $dbport = $dbconnect * 1;
        } else {
            $dbsocket = $dbconnect;
        }
    }
    echo "Port: " . $dbport . "\nSocket: " . $dbsocket;
    wp_die();
}
```

This is not expected to work when somebody is not logged in as an admin, so I omitted the no_priv add_action. I am certain this is not the problem; I did add that into my code and it had no impact.

What newbie mistake have I made? :)

Comment: Maybe this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933027/why-am-i-getting-a-status-code-400-bad-request-error-with-wp-ajax/64933198?noredirect=1#comment115045020_64933198

Comment: Although I am prone to typos, I could not find one here. If I have one, please point it out, but I think I have been consistent in function names.

Looking earlier in that post, the one thing I am not sure of and which concerns me most is placement of the add_action hooks. It *looks* to me that it is; the PHP with the hook is included before the PHP with the Ajax function.

Comment: That's not the problem with the execution order. You need to have your hook added before the javascript event occours. The quickest test is to move it to your theme functions.php

Comment: The add_action is before the register/localize/enqueue. Which part should be moved to the functions.php? Ultimately, I don't want to do this; this is a custom plugin I am designing, so there is not a functions.php involved (at least not yet).

Comment: I mean, if your  add_action("wp_ajax_krud_save_new_connection" is inside another function which is getting called by some hook that fire AFTER the admin-ajax.php then you will never get a successful response. If you are designing a plugin, its still good. Move the  add_action("wp_ajax_krud_save_new_connection" into your main plugin file (the one with the special comments header for WP) outside of any class declaration. Like the first or last line in the file and see if that work :)

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work any better. Then I moved the add_action outside of the if structure and it worked. The other part inside the same if was working--it was a require once and that part was there, so the condition was passing. I will put it off to WordPress and PHP weirdness.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course, now it's doing something else weird. I am getting a 0 back from the Ajax call instead of the string I expect. Not sure what it's actually executing when I make the call. But mysteries like this are why we love coding!

Comment: Apparently, my conditional was failing after all. I will shush now.

Answer (score 0):

First, enqueue the script and then localize the script for ajax. It will fix the issue. Check the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I tried that, no joy. I reversed the enqueue and localize lines, but I still get the 400 Bad Request. The working Ajax has the localize first.